# Registering Javascript function that manipulates radwindow from ajaxified radgrid

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-ajax, radwindow

I'm trying to open a radwindow client side with some registered script.

Question 1: Is there a reason radwindow wouldn't be found if executed on startup, if so why and how do I fix it?

Question 2: Whenever I ajaxify the radgrid the event no longer fires. This makes sense, as there is not a postback occurring, so the page never starts up. How do I get registered scripts to execute in an ajax enviornment?

---- Relevant Code Behind ----

```
    protected void RadgridProjects_ItemCommand(object source, Telerik.Web.UI.GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Member")
        {
            Session["ProjectId"] = (e.Item as GridDataItem).GetDataKeyValue("ProjectId").ToString();
            radGridProjectMembers.Rebind();   //Not the same grid!

            ClientScriptManager cs = Page.ClientScript;

            string js = "<script type='text/javascript'>ShowWindow()</script>";
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showwindow", js);

        }
     }
```

---- Javascript Function ----

```
     function ShowWindow()
    {
            alert("code fired");
            var radWin = $find("<%= RadWindow1.ClientID %>");
            radWin.show();

            radWin.moveTo(650, 450);
            radWin.set_width(500);
            radWin.set_height(400);
    }
```

The window never opens, but my testing alert does fire. It should be noted that when I use a client event for the script the window DOES open.

Comment: Your script has to run after that element referred to in the `$find()` call is added to the DOM. Try moving the `<script>` block to the very end of the `<body>`.

Comment: Good point on reason for error, but Changing the script location did not help. Though I didn't expect it to. Wouldn't startup scripts and adding elements to the DOM occur on separate parts of the page lifecycle?

Comment: No, `<script>` blocks are parsed and evaluated the moment the browser sees the closing tag.  If the script is before an element it references, the element won't be present in the DOM. Now, if there's more code than what you posted, and that function is called by a "load" or "ready" handler, then there'd be no problem.

Comment: I placed the script at the very bottom of the page, but the result did not change.